# how to make python manage.py runserver still running if terminal close?

Tags: server, python, django

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` 
how to make this command running if terminal close

for now i use screen and it works any other way to do that?
i mean for production how to link it to ngix or apahce in ubuntu server?

Comment: If your question is not a duplicate please [edit] it to explain why. So far it still looks like a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to run your Python script with the `nohup` command infront. Nohup will make the script immume to hangups.

example

```
nohup python myscript.py &
```

Your output will be send to nohup.out.

Comment: You could also use forever. This is a nodejs script but you can run Python scripts with it. [link](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever)

Comment: This will make the process go to background, but it will not prevent it from being killed if you `exit` the session. To do that one has to use screen or similar, where, as you pointed out, you can use the nohup in addition to screen...

Comment: `nohup python manage.py runserver &` this worked for me. to kill it you need to find the pid using `ps aux | grep manage.py` then kill it using `kill pid`

Answer (score 1):

Very nice alternative to `screen` is program called [**tmux**](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/). I use it constantly for daily basis.

#### **Tip:**

To dump process into same terminal, runcd any command you'd like, then:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> - to stop process
2. write `bg` - it will dump process to the background